# Send plain text to email android

Tags: android, mobile

I want data entered on the below form to be sent to myemail@gmail.com when button is pressed - how can I do this?

[image]

**Code:**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "djalise@gmail.com");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two mistakes in your code :

**#1**

You need to get the text from your `EditText` and convert it to `String` and then put this email `Intent` inside the `onClickListener` of your `Button` :

Try this :

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id. yourButton);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String enteredText = yourEditText.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"myemail@gmail.com"}); //2nd mistake is here.
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, enteredText);                      

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));

    }
});
```

**2nd mistake is here :**

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "djalise@gmail.com");
```

email intent expects an `String array`(as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL)) but you're providing a `String`, so use this :

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"myemail@gmail.com"});
```

**UPDATE**

Since you want to open the Gmail app automatically to send the email, try this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"myemail@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

i.e, you've to add this extra line to set the target class name to `ComposeActivityGmail` :

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
```

Comment: Now my app just crashes when starts, how to fix that?

Comment: 1:10:10 PM PSI and index do not match: PSI and index do not match

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.android.examapp, PID: 2858
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{

Comment: E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.android.examapp.MainActivity.access$super

Comment: hey @AlisaMarčenkova this is not the **FULL** stacktrace, please add the complete error stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: what's the line no. 17 in the MainActivity?

Comment: intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"djalisel@gmail.com"});

Comment: did you change the `EditText` and `Button` ids to your edittext, button id?

Comment: then please share your complete `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`, the error is coming there.

Comment: hey @Alisa you have not set the content view for the activity try writing this : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` line and it will solve the error

Comment: i need all info from this form so, how to get info from another two plain texts send?

Comment: you can get the other texts similarly, like you did for the name : by using `final EditText phoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone); String enteredPhone = phoneEditText.getText().toString();` and similar for all other fields.

Comment: i do that, but now info is collected only from last plain text, what's wrong i did?

Comment: you should not set the `onClickListener` 3 times, as you've done, setting it again overrides the previous listener. I think this is what you need : http://pastebin.com/T69djKhv

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, only one question, can i remove some useless stuff in chooser later?

Comment: you mean the intent chooser?

Comment: what do you want? do you want to open the gmail app automatically?

Comment: yep only gmail not others

Comment: check the updated answer, that will open the gmail app for you.

Comment: can you explain detailed?

Comment: this will start the `ComposeActivity` of the `Gmail` app with the given email, subject and body text.

Comment: actually i don't understand that, where i need to do this

Comment: thanks, it is possible to automatically send this email?

Comment: No but you can send automatic emails by using some API, you can use the JavaMail API.

Comment: btw you can mark the answer as correct so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make your button clickable using [`setOnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)/%22setOnClickListener%22). You also need to get the text from your `EditText` using `getText().toString()`.

To get your `Button` and `EditText` you need to use `findViewById(R.id.your_id);` where *your_id* corresponds to the ID assigned in your XML layout file for the `Button` and `EditText` (more on `findViewById` [here)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)/%22here%22). The IDs will need to be changed to the correct IDs in the code below.

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto", emailAddress, null));
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "djalise@gmail.com");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);                      

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));

    }
});
```

Comment: my app just crash now when starts, where is problem and how fix this crash?

Comment: You will have to post the crash log in logcat for me to be able to see why it crashes. Did you change the IDs for button and edit text to match whatever is in your XML file like I meantioned in my answer? Logcat usually tells you the exact line of code that's causing the crash.